# PHP: extract number of indexed pages in Google with preg_match (not Google API)

Tags: php, preg-match

I am using cURL to fetch the number of results of a certain search in Google.

I use **preg_match** to extract the data like this:

```
preg_match('/About (.*?) results/sim',$google_url_contents, $regs)
```

and like this:

```
preg_match('/Results .*? of about (.*?) from/sim', $google_url_contents, $regs)
```

However, for less than 10 results I don't have a *text string* before the number, so I don't know how to parse it.

The HTML output presented by Google looks like this:

```
<div id="resultStats">6 results<nobr>  (0.11 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>
```

In this example, how could I extract the **6** as an *integer*?

**NOTE**: I do not want to use **Google Search API** for the moment.

Comment: Can you give an example of a search that yields less than 10 results? P.S. using RegEx to parse HTML is like a stigma around here.

\d is for any digit. \d+ is for one or more digits. [0-9]+ is one or more of any digit between 0 and 9. In another words, you can use `/\d+ results/`

Comment: I know RegEx is not popular... here's an example of search with less than 10 results: `http://www.google.com/#q=site:www.yogamesana.com`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match('/resultStats\D*([\d,]+)/', $line, $matches)`

```
function get_number_of_results($line) {
    if (preg_match('/resultStats\D*([\d,]+)/', $line, $matches)) {
        echo "$matches[1]\n";   # for debug only
        $value = (int) str_replace(',', '', $matches[1]);
        return $value;
    }  
    return -1;  
}

$line = '<div id="resultStats">6 results<nobr>  (0.11 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>';
var_dump(get_number_of_results($line));

$line = '<div id="resultStats">About 6,100,000 results<nobr>  (0.11 seconds)&nbsp;</nobr></div>';
var_dump(get_number_of_results($line));
```

Output:

```
6
int(6)
6,100,000
int(6100000)
```

The `\D` means a non-digit character.  `\D*` is 0 or more non-digit characters.  `[\d,]` is a character class of either a digit or a comma, and `[\d,]+` means 1 or more of them.